# Angular & TypeScript Promise

Tags: angularjs

I'm sorry about my English but I'm not fluent.

I've a problem and I don't understand why when I use Google Chrome with the other's broswers the web aplication works correctly.

The problem is when I make click in the buttom logout using Google Chrome the web page don't do the logout in the first time I click above the logout. But when I click the second time works correctly and I'm redirected to the logout page.

With other's browsers work at the first time but not with google chrome
Here is the code and thank you very much.

```
logout() {
    let token = this.token.rcs().token;
    this.token.removeAllTokens();

    let redirect = () => {
        //oauthState.config.logoutRedirect && window.location.replace(oauthState.config.logoutRedirect);
        window.location.replace(oauthState.config.logoutRedirect);
        /* oauthState.config.logoutRedirect send me to the logout page. */
    };

    let redirect1 = () => {
        alert("error tt")
    };

    this.$http
    .post(oauthState.config.baseAuthUrl.concat('/').concat(oauthState.config.revokePath), {token: token.accessToken}, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(redirect, redirect1);
}
```

Comment: Is response  is successful on the first call in JS?

Comment: Only if used another browser that not is google chrome. If I use google chrome I need to click two times in the botton logout. The redirect function is executed when I click to times above the botton logout in google chrome

Comment: So you need to click two times before to run only one request?

Comment: Yes onlye in google chrome. When I click two time the callback execute the functon redirect.